# Какой тип и индекс задавать ячейке с порядковым номеров в mySQL

Tags: mysql

Я пытаюсь создать таблицу в mySQL, которая будет хранить несколько тысяч строк. Какой тип, длину и индекс задать для ячейки, которая соответствует порядковому номеру записи? В частности столбец Индекс может принимать значения Unique и Index, мне кажется по смыслу подходят оба. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: делайте обычный `int` и не парьтесь. размер задавать не обязательно. index - это вообще то для ускорения поиска, он не обязательно уникальный. то что вы хотите - очень похоже на первичный ключ, так что объявляйте primary key по этому полю, а уникальный индекс MySQL в этом случае сам сделает

Comment: @Mike спасибо!!